# How to solve this system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ be a given "nice" function and let $a,b:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be two unknown functions to be solved for (with some initial conditions $a(0),a'(0),b(0),b'(0))$.

How can one solve the following equation: $$ f(x) = \exp\left(-\mathrm{i}\int_0^x\cos(a(y))b'(y)\mathrm{d}y\right)\left(a'(x)+\mathrm{i}\sin(a(x))b'(x)\right)\qquad(x\in[0,1])\,? \tag{E}$$

I'm a bit stumped by the mis-match of the $\sin$ and $\cos$. For example, had the equation been $$ f(x) = \exp\left(-\mathrm{i}\int_0^x\cos(a(y))b'(y)\mathrm{d}y\right)\left(a'(x)-\mathrm{i}\cos(a(x))b'(x)\right)\qquad(x\in[0,1]) $$we could have re-written the RHS as $$ \left(a \exp\left(-\mathrm{i}\int_0^\cdot\cos(a)b'\right)\right)'  $$ so that $$ \int_0^x f = a(x) \exp\left(-\mathrm{i}\int_0^x\cos(a(y))b'(y)\mathrm{d}y\right) $$ and we could have found $a,b$ by looking at the absolute value or respectively the phase of the LHS.

However, due to the mismatch between the cosine and sine in (E) I am not sure how to proceed, though I hope it does not mean that there isn't a closed form solution.

Comment: The $\displaystyle\exp\left(-\mathrm i\int_0^x\cos(a(y))b'(y)\,\mathrm dy\right)$ term seems quite conspicuous. Where is Equation E derived from?

Comment: Also, even for $f = 0$ (being “nice” enough) with the initial conditions $a(0)=a'(0)=0$ and arbitrarily given $b(0)$ and $b'(0)$, there're infinitely many solutions:$$\begin{cases}a(x) = 0\\b(x)=b(0)+b'(0)x+cx^2\end{cases},$$where $c\in\mathbb R$ is any constant.

Comment: @Saad, thanks for your comments. The equation comes from doing parallel transport on the sphere ($a,b$ being the spherical coordinates). I think the case you point out is quite degenerate, perhaps one should insist on initial conditions where the derivatives are not zero.

Comment: Did you try to look at the absolute value and the phase on the first equation?

Comment: @jvc, thanks, yes, I tried. The absolute value equation is easy, but I don't know what to do with the phase equation then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**REVISED.**

Assume the equation
$$
f(x)=\exp\left(-i\int^{x}_{0}\cos(a(y))b'(y)dy\right)[a'(x)+i\sin(a(x))b'(x)],\tag 1
$$
where $f:\textbf{R}\rightarrow\textbf{C}$ and $a(x),b(x)$ are $\textbf{R}\rightarrow\textbf{R}$.

Seting $a(y)=t$ in (1) we get
$$
f(x)=\exp\left(-i\int^{a(x)}_{a(0)}\cos(t) b'\left(a^{(-1)}(t)\right)a^{(-1)}{'}(t)dt\right)[a'(x)+i\sin(a(x))b'(x)]\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
f\left(a^{(-1)}(x)\right)=\exp\left(-i\int^{x}_{a(0)}\cos(t)\left(b\left(a^{(-1)}(t)\right)\right)'dt\right)\times
$$
$$
\times [\frac{1}{a^{(-1)}{'}(x)}+i\sin(x)b'\left(a^{(-1)}(x)\right)]\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
a^{(-1)}{'}(x)f\left(a^{(-1)}(x)\right)=\exp\left(-i\int^{x}_{c}\cos(t)g'(t)dt\right)[1+i\sin(x)g'(x)],\tag 2
$$
where $c_0=a(0)$ and $g(x)=b\left(a^{(-1)}(x)\right)$. Hence (2) becomes
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int^{a^{(-1)}(x)}_{c_1}f(t)dt=e^{-iY}-e^{-iY}(-i\cos(x)g'(x))\tan(x),\tag 3
$$
where 
$$
Y=Y(x):=\int^{x}_{c_0}\cos(t)g'(t)dt.
$$ 
Hence if we also set
$$
H(x):=\int^{a^{(-1)}(x)}_{c_1}f(t)dt\tag 4
$$
and $f(t)=f_1(t)+if_2(t)$, with $f_1,f_2$ real, then 
$$
H_{j}(x)=\int^{a^{(-1)}(x)}_{c_0}f_j(t)dt\in\textbf{R}\textrm{, } j=1,2.\tag{4.1}
$$ 
Hence
$$
H(x)=H_1(x)+iH_2(x).
$$
But then
$$
H'(x)=e^{-iY}-\frac{d\left(e^{-iY}\right)}{dx}\tan(x)\tag 5
$$
Setting lastly $e^{-iY}=w(x)$, we get
$$
H'(x)=w(x)-w'(x)\tan(x)\Leftrightarrow
$$ 
$$
w(x)=-\sin(x)\int^{x}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}H'(x)dx\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
\exp\left(-i\int^{x}_{c_0}\cos(t)g'(t)dt\right)=-\sin(x)\int^{x}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}H'(t)dt.\tag 6
$$
Hence
$$
\cos\left(\int^{x}_{c_0}\cos(t)g'(t)dt\right)=-\sin(x)\int^{x}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}H_1'(t)dt\tag 7
$$
and
$$
\sin\left(\int^{x}_{c_0}\cos(t)g'(t)dt\right)=\sin(x)\int^{x}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}H_2'(t)dt\tag 8
$$

Solving (8) with respect to $g'(x)$, we get
$$
\int^{x}_{c_0}\cos(t)g'(t)dt=\sin^{(-1)}\left(\sin(x)\int^{x}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}H_2'(t)dt\right)\Rightarrow
$$
$$
g(x)=b\left(a^{(-1)}(x)\right)=
$$
$$
=\int^{x}_{c_3}\frac{1}{\cos(u)}\frac{d}{du}\left[\sin^{(-1)}\left(\sin(u)\int^{u}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}H_2'(t)dt\right)\right]du.
$$
Hence 
$$
b(x)=\int^{a(x)}_{c_3}\frac{\csc^2(u)H_2'(u)}{\sqrt{1-\left(\int^{u}_{c_2}\cot(t)\csc(t)H_2'(t)dt\right)^2}}du,\tag 9
$$
Now from (7) and (8), we have
$$
\left(\int^{x}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}H_1'(t)dt\right)^2+\left(\int^{x}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}H_2'(t)dt\right)^2=\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}
$$
Hence we can assume that exists real function $\phi(x)$ with inverse $\theta(x)$ such that
$$
\sin(x)\int^{x}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}H_1'(t)dt=\cos(\phi(x))\tag{10}
$$
and
$$
\sin(x)\int^{x}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}H_2'(t)dt=\sin(\phi(x))\tag{11}
$$
Hence
$$
\int^{\theta(x)}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}H_1'(t)dt=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(\theta(x))}
$$
and
$$
\int^{\theta(x)}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}H_2'(t)dt=\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(\theta(x))}
$$
Differentiating these formulas we get
$$
\sin(x)+\cot(\theta(x))[\cos(x)+H_1'(\theta(x))\theta'(x)]=0\tag{12}
$$
and
$$
\cos(x)-\cot(\theta(x))[\sin(x)+H_2'(\theta(x))\theta'(x)]=0\tag{13}
$$
Solving (12) with respect to $\theta'(x)$, we get
$$
\theta'(x)=-\frac{\sin(x)\tan(\theta(x))}{\cos(x)+H_1'(\theta(x))}.\tag{14}
$$
Setting this value of $\theta'(x)$ in (13) we get 
$$
H_2'\left(\theta(x)\right)=-\csc(x)-\cot(x)H_1'(\theta(x)).\tag{15}
$$
Now using (4),(4.1) we get
$$
a^{(-1)}{'}\left(\theta(x)\right)=\frac{-1}{\cos(x)f_1\left(a^{(-1)}\left(\theta(x)\right)\right)+\sin(x)f_2\left(a^{(-1)}\left(\theta(x)\right)\right)}\tag{15.1}
$$
and
$$
\theta'(x)=\tan(\theta(x))\frac{\cos(x)f_1\left(a^{(-1)}\left(\theta(x)\right)\right)+\sin(x)f_2\left(a^{(-1)}\left(\theta(x)\right)\right)}{\sin(x)f_1\left(a^{(-1)}\left(\theta(x)\right)\right)-\cos(x)f_2\left(a^{(-1)}\left(\theta(x)\right)\right)}.\tag{15.2}
$$
**Notes**.

1. $f'(g(x))$ is not $(f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x))g'(x)$.
2. In general if $h(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$, then holds $f(h(x))=h(f(x))=x$ and $f'(h(x))=\frac{1}{h'(x)}$ and $h'(f(x))=\frac{1}{f'(x)}$.

Hence equivalently if $A(x)$ denotes the inverse of $a(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ the inverse of $\theta(x)$:
$$
A'(x)=\frac{-1}{\cos(\phi(x))f_1\left(A\left(x\right)\right)+\sin(\phi(x))f_2\left(A\left(x\right)\right)}\tag{16}
$$
$$
\phi'(x)=\cot(x)\frac{\sin(\phi(x))f_1\left(A\left(x\right)\right)-\cos(\phi(x))f_2\left(A\left(x\right)\right)}{\cos(\phi(x))f_1\left(A\left(x\right)\right)+\sin(\phi(x))f_2\left(A\left(x\right)\right)}\tag{17}
$$

For given $f=f_1+if_2$ the equations (9),(16),(17) are determine the problem in the case of $a(x),b(x)$ real functions. The DE are not linear and quite involved. Hence very hard to solve.

**REMARK**.

If we assume that $b(x)$ not necesary real, then (with notation independent of that above):

Assume the equation
$$
f(x)=\exp\left(-i\int^{x}_{0}\cos(a(y))b'(y)dy\right)[a'(x)+i\sin(a(x))b'(x)].\tag{R1}
$$
Seting $a(y)=t$, we get
$$
f(x)=\exp\left(-i\int^{a(x)}_{a(0)}\cos(t) b'\left(a^{(-1)}(t)\right)a^{(-1)}{'}(t)dt\right)[a'(x)+i\sin(a(x))b'(x)]\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
f\left(a^{(-1)}(x)\right)=\exp\left(-i\int^{x}_{a(0)}\cos(t)\left(b\left(a^{(-1)}(t)\right)\right)'dt\right)\times
$$
$$
\times[\frac{1}{a^{(-1)}{'}(x)}+i\sin(x)b'\left(a^{(-1)}(x)\right)]\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
a^{(-1)}{'}(x)f\left(a^{(-1)}(x)\right)=\exp\left(-i\int^{x}_{c}\cos(t)g'(t)dt\right)[1+i\sin(x)g'(x)],\tag{R2}
$$
where $c_0=a(0)$ and $g(x)=b\left(a^{(-1)}(x)\right)$. Hence (R2) becomes
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int^{a^{(-1)}(x)}_{c_1}f(t)dt=e^{-iY}-e^{-iY}(-i\cos(x)g'(x))\tan(x),\tag{R3}
$$
where 
$$
Y=Y(x):=\int^{x}_{c_0}\cos(t)g'(t)dt.
$$ 
Hence if we also set
$$
H(x):=\int^{a^{(-1)}(x)}_{c_1}f(t)dt,\tag{R4}
$$
then from (R3): 
$$
H'(x)=e^{-iY}-\frac{d\left(e^{-iY}\right)}{dx}\tan(x)
$$
Setting lastly $e^{-iY}=w(x)$, we get
$$
H'(x)=w(x)-w'(x)\tan(x)\Leftrightarrow
$$ 
$$
w(x)=\left(C_1-\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}H'(x)dx\right)\sin(x)\Leftrightarrow
$$
$$
\exp\left(-i\int^{x}_{c_0}\cos(t)g'(t)dt\right)=\sin(x)\left(C_1-\int^{x}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}H'(t)dt\right),\tag{R5}
$$
where $H(x)=\int^{a^{(-1)}(x)}_{c_0}f(t)dt$. Solving (R4) with respect to $g'(x)$, we get
$$
-i\int^{x}_{c_0}\cos(t)g'(t)dt=\log\left(C_1\sin(x)-\sin(x)\int^{x}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}H'(t)dt\right)\Rightarrow
$$
$$
g(x)=b\left(a^{(-1)}(x)\right)=
$$
$$
=i\int^{x}_{c}\frac{1}{\cos(u)}\frac{d}{du}\left[\log\left(\sin(u)\left(C_1-\int^{u}_{c_2}\frac{\cos(t)}{\sin^2(t)}H'(t)dt\right)\right)\right]du.
$$
Hence 
$$
b\left(a^{(-1)}(x)\right)=i\log\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-i\int^{x}_{c_3}\frac{\csc^2(u)H'(u)}{C_1-\int^{u}_{c_2}\cot(t)\csc(t)H'(t)dt}du.\tag{R6}
$$
Hence if $a(x)$ is any (real invertible and smooth) function, then $b(x)$ is given from (R6).

Comment: Thanks! So just to clarify, this only finds solutions where $a$ is invertible and sufficiently regular, but is otherwise unconstrained?

Comment: Another question: the solution should be real which is not manifestly obvious from (6). Do you have a clue about that?

Comment: So after you revision, $a,b$ are manifestly real and $a$ is not arbitrary.

Comment: @PPR. Yes if $a,b$ are real, then they depend on $Re(f)$ and $Im(f)$ and thus are unique. Equations (15),(16) show this better. However if $a,b$ are arbitray (complex numbers etc), then $a(x)$ becomes a parameter and $b(x)$ is evaluated from $a(x)$.

Comment: Im asking sorry. I mean equations (16),(17).

Comment: Nikos, it would be nice if you could clearly state in the end the result for $a$ explicitly. Also, it would go a long way to clean up the notation a bit: the inverse function to $a$ could get its own letter, and removing arguments from functions when this doesn't create ambiguities.